# USB security dongle doesn't get recognised in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: usb, usb-modeswitch

I have an accounting software that runs on Windows and (as per the advice of the user support) Ubuntu. The software comes with a USB dongle which is required to run the software.

My problem is that Ubuntu doesn't recognise the dongle at all, even though I can see the device listed in lsusb command.

Help, anyone?

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: If it needs a USB device driver for Windows, it may need USB-modeswitch settings for **Ubuntu**.

Answer (score 0):

May be your application has no access rights to that USB? Try setting 0666 on its file in /dev once. No matter the result, don't forget to turn it back as it is a security flaw.